# Remove listener from ServletContext

Tags: java, servlets, listener, servlet-3.0, servlet-listeners

I am wondering how I can remove an `EventListener` from a `ServletContext` (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html). The later offers a `addListener` method but nothing to remove a listener. Are listeners maybe hold by weak references and can be deregistered by loosing all strong references? Or what happens if my application is undeployed? Is the listener still active?

Comment: why and when do you need to remove eventlistner from context ? what is the scenario ?

Comment: I write a custom `Servlet` which needs to be aware of all sessions created. Therefore, I add a `SessionListener` programatically during the `Servlet`'s `init` method. Now I wanted to make sure that this listener does not survive the Servlet and wanted to deregister the listener on the `Servlet`'s `destroy` method.

Comment: your approach is wrong. SessionListener is for a webApp not for a servlet. Even if you access some other servlet, a session would be created.

Comment: Well, my `Servlet` is deployed manually, i.e. within a running server and via the `addServlet` method. The servlet itself is independent of any other application. Therefore, there is no other way. If your answer was right, the method `addListener` should not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer to the question , I would just like to make few points .

> The later offers a addListener method but nothing to remove a listener.

Because you need to make a decision initially whether to have a listener or not . Look at the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html):

> Interface for receiving notification events about ServletContext lifecycle changes.
>
> In order to receive these notification events, the implementation **class must be either declared in the deployment descriptor of the web application, annotated with WebListener, or registered via one of the addListener methods defined on ServletContext.**

The [addListener()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addListener(java.lang.String)) gives you a provision to register multiple types of listener , not just the `ServletContextListener`. It is just a method which could be used by you in case you choose not to declare the listeners up front in *web.xml*.

> The given listener must be an instance of one or more of the following interfaces:
>
> 1. ServletContextAttributeListener
> 2. ServletRequestListener
> 3. ServletRequestAttributeListener
> 4. HttpSessionListener
> 5. HttpSessionAttributeListener

---

> what happens if my application is undeployed

All the listener objects will be destroyed along with the app. Listeners are instantiated and registered in the Web container at the time of the deployment of the Web application.

Listener classes are declared in the Web application deployment descriptor using the listener element. They are listed by class name in the order in which they are to be invoked. During Web application execution, listeners are invoked in the order of their registration. On application shutdown, listeners are notified in REVERSE order to their declarations with notifications to session listeners preceding notifications to context listeners. Session listeners must be notified of session invalidation prior to context listeners being notified of application shutdown.

Comment: Why is this not an answer to my question? Thank you a lot!

Comment: When can the `addListener()` method be called ? I'm calling it through a servlet filter hosted on jetty and I'm having an `IllegalStateException` !